# Using Sinon to change how object is instantiated

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, aws-sdk, sinon

I'm using a library that creates a new instance of the DynamoDB object from the AWS SDK: `new AWS.DynamoDB()`.

In my tests, I'd like this library to instantiate the DynamoDB object with a special configuration, i.e. `new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: '...' })`.

Is it possible to accomplish this with Sinon or do I need to modify the 3rd party library to support custom DynamoDB configurations?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to avoid any errors you get without having proper configurations in your test environment, then you can use [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) which has [built in support for configurations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock#dont-worry-about-the-constructor-configuration) so you won't have to worry about setting any special configurations.

Otherwise, if you want to test custom DynamoDB configurations I don't believe it's possible through any library (and personally I don't really see the use-case for it)